# MSBuildProjectDirectory not resolving for MSBuild.ExtensionPack

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, msbuild

I'm working on an ASP.NET 4 WebAPI project and am including a wpp.targets file. I need to use MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile to replace a value in one of my configuration XML files.

The problem is that I don't want to install MSBuild.ExtensionPack on all the machines so I packaged it up with the project. On my local build, the path to the MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll resolves correctly. On my build machine though, I keep getting this error: `The "MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll.`

It seems to be resolving to the default install location of the package.

Here's what's in my wpp.targets file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Sets the assembly which will run the transformation on Web.config (Should be installed on Dev machines) -->
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml"
           AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"/>

<!-- Get the path to the MSBuild.Extension.Pack -->
<PropertyGroup>
    <TPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\packages\MSBuild.Extension.Pack.1.3.0\tools\net40\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks</TPath>
    <TPath Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\packages\MSBuild.Extension.Pack.1.3.0\tools\net40\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks')">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\packages\MSBuild.Extension.Pack.1.3.0\tools\net40\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks</TPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<!--Import the MSBuild.Extension.Pack package -->
<Import Project="$(TPath)"/>

<!-- Make sure web.config and transformation files exist -->
<Target Name="ConfigurationTransform" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="Exists('Web.config')" />
<Target Name="ConfigurationTransform" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="Exists('Web.$(Configuration).config')" />

<!-- Make sure web.config will be there even for package/publish -->
<Target Name="CopyWebConfig" BeforeTargets="Build;Rebuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="Web.Base.config"
          DestinationFiles="Web.config"
          OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"
          SkipUnchangedFiles="false" />
</Target>

<!-- Run Web.Config transformation on a build as well (not just a publish) -->
<Target Name="CustomTransformWebConfigOnBuild" AfterTargets="CopyWebConfig" >
    <Message Text="Transforming: Web.$(Configuration).config" Importance="high" />
    <TransformXml Source="Web.Base.config"
                  Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config"
                  Destination="Web.config" />
</Target>

<!-- Update Web.Config's config attribute -->
<Target Name="UpdateConfigAttribute" AfterTargets="CustomTransformWebConfigOnBuild" Condition="$(Configuration) != 'Release'">
    <Message Text="Transforming: Web.config" Importance="high" />       
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile TaskAction="UpdateAttribute"
                                       File="Web.config"
                                       XPath="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='config_url']"
                                       Key="value"
                                       Value="www.randomurl.com"/>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have more than 1 option for the source location for a helper-dll...I like to do it like with the style below.

Something like this (Obviously, you'll have to put real locations in for "PossibleLocationOne" and "PossibleLocationTwo").

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MyFoundMSBuildExtensionPackLocation Condition="Exists('..\PossibleLocationOne\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll')">..\PossibleLocationOne\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll</MyFoundMSBuildExtensionPackLocation>
    <MyFoundMSBuildExtensionPackLocation Condition="Exists('..\PossibleLocationTwo\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll')">..\PossibleLocationTwo\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll</MyFoundMSBuildExtensionPackLocation>
    <!--Now check to see if either of the two above resolved , if not , add something to the path so you can at least -->
    <MyFoundMSBuildExtensionPackLocation Condition="'$(MyFoundMSBuildExtensionPackLocation)'==''">DID_NOT_FIND_A_PATH_FOR_MSBUILDEXENSIONPACK\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll</MyFoundMSBuildExtensionPackLocation>
</PropertyGroup>

<UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(MyFoundMSBuildExtensionPackLocation)" TaskName="TransformXml"/>
```

Add all options for possible locations..and one extra for "I didn't find a match"....

Then use the "UsingTask".

"UsingTask" is ~~after~~ the MyFoundMSBuildExtensionPackLocation(PropertyGroup).......so the $(MyFoundMSBuildExtensionPackLocation) resolves before the UsingTask is called.